# roaming Exchange/Outlook users also need POP3 accounts

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook, pop3

I have 10 **Win SBS 2008 User Accounts** and 10 PC's. Three of the persons who are associated to the user accounts work at different PC's each day. These three people also do have **POP3-Emails** which have to be accessed by **MS Outlook**.

I know there is the possibility of adding the **pop3-email login credentials** into each Outlook installation on each PC manually. But there must be a more elegant way using the MS Exchange server 2007.

The MS exchange Server 2007 has already installed a **pop3-connector** which successfully links one of the ten Win SBS 2008 User accounts with pop3-email so that the user has access on every machine without manually inputting the pop3-email credentials.

**What do I have to do to make the same thing for the other user accounts to happen?**

*Please let me know if i forgot to give you important information.*

Comment: Please use better question titles. Your previous one was pretty useless. I updated it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a mailbox for each of those POP3 accounts. Use the POP3 connector to get the mail for those accounts. Give the necessary users "Full Access" permissions to those mailboxes. You might also want to give them "Send As" or "Send on Behalf Of" permissions.

Comment: Is the "create mailbox" function inside MS Exchange 2007 or somewhere else? Where can i access the Pop3 connector's options?

Comment: I have found how to access the Pop3 settings: 1.) Open Windows SBS console 2.) Select Network 3.) Select Connectivity 4.) Select the Pop3 connector.